# How to add dynamically functions into html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending html from server side to client side, and in the the client side i am catching the html and trying to insert JS/JQ function to it.

this is the html:

```
    <div align=center style=background-image:url(/srv/admin/img/announcement/error_dynamic_icon.gif);height:70px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:50% 50%;background-position:50% 50%>. </div>
<li id=announcement4 class=announcement>
   <table class=tg>
      <tr>
         <th class=tg-031e rowspan=3 style=background-image:url(/srv/admin/img/announcement/maintenance_icon.png);background-position:50% 50%></th>
         <th rowspan=3 class=border_separator></th>
         <th class=title_style colspan=2>Title - 3 test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=tg_text colspan=2>Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. ?no great but music too old found arose. </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class=r2>
         <td class=tg-031e></td>
         <td class=tg-031e><input id=button4 type=button  class=ajax_btn_right value=Confirm ></input><input id=checkbox4 type=checkbox class=ajax_checkbox ></input></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</li>
<li id=announcement6 class=announcement>
   <table class=tg>
      <tr>
         <th class=tg-031e rowspan=3 style=background-image:url(/srv/admin/img/announcement/general_message_icon.png);background-position:50% 50%></th>
         <th rowspan=3 class=border_separator></th>
         <th class=title_style colspan=2>Title - 5 test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=tg_text colspan=2>Now led tedious shy lasting females off. Dashwood marianne in of entrance be on wondered possible building. Wondered sociable he carriage in speedily margaret. Up devonshire of he thoroughly insensible alteration. An mr settling occasion insisted distance ladyship so. Not attention say frankness intention out dashwoods now curiosity. Stronger ecstatic as no judgment daughter speedily thoughts. Worse downs nor might she court did nay forth these. </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class=r2>
         <td class=tg-031e></td>
         <td class=tg-031e><input id=button6 type=button  class=ajax_btn_right value=Confirm ></input><input id=checkbox6 type=checkbox class=ajax_checkbox ></input></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</li>
<li id=announcement7 class=announcement>
   <table class=tg>
      <tr>
         <th class=tg-031e rowspan=3 style=background-image:url(/srv/admin/img/announcement/external_link_icon.png);background-position:50% 50%></th>
         <th rowspan=3 class=border_separator></th>
         <th class=title_style colspan=2>Title - 6 test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=tg_text colspan=2>Increasing impression interested expression he my at. Respect invited request charmed me warrant to. Expect no pretty as do though so genius afraid cousin. Girl when of ye snug poor draw. Mistake totally of in chiefly. Justice visitor him entered for. Continue delicate as unlocked entirely mr relation diverted in. Known not end fully being style house. An whom down kept lain name so at easy. </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class=r2>
         <td class=tg-031e></td>
         <td class=tg-031e><input id=button7 type=button  class=ajax_btn_right value=Confirm ></input><input id=checkbox7 type=checkbox class=ajax_checkbox ></input></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</li>
<div class=footer align=center>Please confirm you have read and acted upon this message</div>
```

using jquery or javascript i want to add to each button a function, base on their class or id.
to on click event.
for eaxample:

```
         jQuery.each( all buttons with the class/id name, function(add function to the button ) {
alert( 'hello world' );
});
```

Comment: Add function to button? Not sure I understand what you mean by that

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried? Where have you looked for an answer?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org)

Comment: @user2706762 You can use `.bind()`. See my answer for further detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539120/how-to-add-dynamically-functions-into-html/23539146#23539146)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a delegated event handler. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myElement', function() {
    alert('hello world');
});
```

I used `document` as the primary selector as an example. You should use the closest element to those dynamically appended.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/8UxWJ/2/)**

You can use ;

```
$( ".class_name" ).bind( "click", function() {
  // your code here
});
```